# Universal Server Side Rendering stops Rendering Content after Installing PWA in Angular 6.0.3

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I've built a simple Angular 6 application and integrated Universal into it by following this tutorial: [Angular Universal Tutorial](https://angularfirebase.com/snippets/angular-6-universal-simple-guide/)

Link to GitHub repo that I created: [Angular Universal SSR GitHub Repo](https://github.com/cstodor/Angular-Universal-PWA-SSR)

Universal SSR is working great, it renders content (both static and dynamic from Firebase Real Time Database and Firestore) without any issues, however, after I install PWA following the official documentations from [PWA tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started), Universal SSR stops working without any errors... but PWA works.

Can anyone tell me why SSR stops working after installing PWA?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: perhaps install PWA BEFORE universal?

Comment: @Csaba I have to same issue how you fix it?

Comment: I'm having the same issue on https://tuinvoice.com/ , the first pageview the content is SSRendered OK, but after that it's always frontend rendered, did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I found something that worked for my website but I'm using a new version of angular and universal

```
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.803.19",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~8.2.4",
    "@ng-toolkit/universal": "^7.1.2"
```

[How to make Angular Universal and PWA work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56383569/how-to-make-angular-universal-and-pwa-work-together/58936219#58936219)

Answer (score 1):

When you Angular PWA (service worker) to Angular SSR project.

> - Kindly add `"navigationUrls": []` in your ngsw-config.json file

The below screen shot will bind SSR html on view source.

[image]

Comment: you saved me hours of debugging