# Angular Universal View Page Source Appearing on Mozilla But Not on Chrome

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I'm confused about the Angular Universal setup. When i run localhost:4000 on Google Chrome, theres no data inside the `<app-root>` but when on Mozilla there a data on it. I saw from docs and tutorials that you know you successfully installed Angular Universal Server Side Rendering on it when there some data inside the `<app-root>`. There's also a service workers installed BTW. Is there any problem with Angular Universal Setup since there's no error when i run it?
Pls see the images below

> RUN COMMAND

[image: Run Command]

> GOOGLE CHROME

[image: GOOGLE CHROME]

> MOZILLA FIREFOX

[image: Mozilla Firefox]

Comment: What if you uninstall the service worker in chrome, then open `view-source:http://localhost:4000` in another tab straight away?

Comment: @David. Oh. Maybe service worker and server side rendering doesn't work together?

Comment: Does that help? It looks like your problem  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56383569/how-to-make-angular-universal-and-pwa-work-together